# NodeJS web-socket server explodes at around 1,000 connections

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, network-programming

I'm using [websocket/ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) which is known to be one of the fastest available implementations for web-sockets using NodeJS. However I'm only able to get to around 1,000 connections before Node decides that it's completely done doing much of anything. Once it hits about 900 connections it becomes sluggish, and then comes to a halt.

Here's my implementation (Basic echo server):

```
var wss    = require('ws').Server;
var ws     = require('ws');
var server = new wss({port:8080});
var connections = 0;

server.on('connection', function connection(socket) {
    connections++;

    socket.on('message', function incoming(data) {
        socket.send(data);
    });

    socket.on('close', function ack() {
        connections--;
    });
});

setInterval(function() {
    printConnections();
}, 5000);

function printConnections() {
    console.log("Connected clients: " + connections);
}
```

The amount of connections connected displayed by the server is always equal to the amount of connections listed by the clients, so this isn't the issue. I've tried using multiple computers on separate networks to break the 1,000 user limit (To see if it was home network bandwidth limitations) and it wasn't. SSH also becomes highly unresponsive at this point.

Server specs:

```
- 1Gbit ethernet. 
- Three full, dedicated HT CPU cores (Nehalem or better)
- 3072 MB of RAM
- Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS
```

When the server is running (at 1,000 users) there is still plenty of memory to spare. Trying to figure out what the issue is here, as we're working on a server for a mobile application and 1,000 concurrent users is only scratching the surface. We're aiming for around 100,000 concurrent users. We will definitely improve hardware (And get a dedicated machine) when we go live, but we should be able to get much more out of our current setup.

I should also add that the following modifications have been done while attempting to fix the issue:

```
ulimit -n 1000000
sysctl -w fs.file-max = 1000000
sysctl -w fs.nr_open = 1000000  
sysctl -w net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 1048576
sysctl -w net.nf_conntrack_max = 1048576
```

Comment: Some good reading: [Nodejs with 1000000 concurrent connections](http://blog.caustik.com/2012/08/19/node-js-w1m-concurrent-connections/), [600k concurrent websocket connections on AWS using Node.js](http://www.jayway.com/2015/04/13/600k-concurrent-websocket-connections-on-aws-using-node-js/) and [Scaling node.js to 100k concurrent connections](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4359684).  All these from a Google search for "node.js thousands of connections".

Comment: @jfriend00 - I've read them all.

Comment: Can you check CPU utilization?

Comment: @Hobbyist - and what did you learn, try and discover after reading and applying everything in those articles?

Comment: @jfriend00 - If Daniel can get 600,000 connections on 4 cores in the cloud, and I can't get 1,500 on a single core with the same setup and options, there's obviously a problem somewhere.

Comment: @rodolk - CPU Usage hovers between 2-10%

Comment: @Hobbyist were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Given your description, and the fact that also ssh and the whole system is affected, you must have a bottleneck somewhere. It is not CPU nor bandwidth, so you should look at memory. Which is the default size of send and receive TCP buffers?

Another possibility, I don't know the environment where you are testing, if you are using any IaaS like AWS or you are testing from your home behind a NAT device (probably a WiFi AP/router), sometimes when you try to open too many connections it is NAT that closes your connections or they timeout after (30-60 sec). If this is the case, you can configure your ssh client to send keep alive messages every 20 sec (I would configure this time or less). This would solve the problem with ssh. Also, in this case, I don't believe you are going to be able to run this kind of test (with this configuration).

Other possibility, if none of the above, is that you test creating two processes listening on different sockets. If you can implement this test with 1K clients connecting to one port and 1K clients connecting to other port, you can figure out if it is a problem of system resources or just process resources.

I hope this helps.